# Swift macOS: Window-Redraw is not working

Tags: swift, macos, redraw

i have coded a window with a NSview and a button. When the program is startet, one point appear in the window. After pressing the button, additional three points should be appear, but the code don't redraw the window. If I set a Breakpoint inside the draw function, I recognize, that the code only stops at the first time in the draw function and the setNeedDisplay-function seems to useless. I have also tried some variations of display() or needDisplay.

Does I make a mistake or can I not code it in this way?

Thanks for any help.

[My Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPUok.png)

My Code:

**ViewController.swift**

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBAction func buttonStart(_ sender: Any) {
        let asd = ViewAnts()
        asd.simulation()
} }
```

**ViewAnts.swift**

```
import Cocoa
@IBDesignable
class ViewAnts: NSView {
    static var tribeAnts = [Ants]()
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        NSColor.white.setFill()
        NSRectFill(dirtyRect)
        ViewAnts.tribeAnts.append(Ants(x: 30, y: 40, size: 2))
        for i in 0...(ViewAnts.tribeAnts.count-1) {
            let point = NSBezierPath()
            point.appendArc(withCenter: NSPoint(x: ViewAnts.tribeAnts[i].x, y: ViewAnts.tribeAnts[i].y), radius: ViewAnts.tribeAnts[i].size, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 360)
            point.stroke()
        }
    }

    func simulation() {
        ViewAnts.tribeAnts.append(Ants(x: 130, y: 40, size: 5))
        ViewAnts.tribeAnts.append(Ants(x: 230, y: 40, size: 5))
        ViewAnts.tribeAnts.append(Ants(x: 20, y: 40, size: 5))

        let rect = NSRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width:CGFloat(500), height: CGFloat(400))
//        needsDisplay = true
        setNeedsDisplay(rect)
//        display(rect)
//        display()
//        draw(rect)
//    display(rect)
    }

}
```

**Ants.swift**

```
import Cocoa
struct Ants {
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
    var size: CGFloat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @IBAction func buttonStart(_ sender: Any) {
>     let asd = ViewAnts()
>     asd.simulation()
> ```

You're instantiating `ViewAnts`, but you never add the view to a window. If you've got a window that contains an instance of `ViewAnts`, perhaps created in Interface Builder, that view is not the one whose `simulation()` method is being called here.

If you're going to create the view in this code, then you need to add the view to your window. Or, if you're going to create the view in IB, then you need to get a reference to that one via an outlet or some other means, and not instantiate the view here.

Comment: I have created the view with the IB and connected the view the ViewAnts class. The breakpoint in the func simulation() stops, but the code don't jumps into the func draw. How can I create the needed reference via outlet?

Comment: " but you never add the view to a window. " Does the the view is not added to the window, if I choose the ViewAnts class as custom class?

Comment: You may have an instance of ViewAnts in your window (the one you created in IB) but again, that's not the one whose `simulation()` method is being called. `asd` in the code above isn't in a window, so it'll never be drawn.